# onclick window.location.href with input multiple value

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, input

I have several check boxes (from the blog label). I use the following code to load whatever labels are selected, but this only works in one label.

I have tried it, but it only works for one check label and the checkbox input goes away and only loads the page

```
/search/?q=label:Topic1
```

my code

```
    <ul>
    <li> <input class="topik" type="checkbox" value="label:topik1"></li>
    <li> <input class="topik" type="checkbox" value="label:topik2"></li>
    <li> <input class="topik" type="checkbox" value="label:topik3"></li>
    <li> <input class="topik" type="checkbox" value="label:topik4"></li>
    <li> <input class="topik" type="checkbox" value="label:topik5"></li>
    </ul>

     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $(".topik").change(function() { 
     window.location.href = '/search/?q=' + this.value;
     });
     });
```

Now the question is I want to be able to run more than one label to choose from. How can I do it in the code?
Now the question is I want to be able to run more than one label to choose from. How can I do it in code?
Makes loading pages with the following format

```
/search/?q=label:Topic1|label:Topic2|label:Topic3
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it is redirecting on change of the input.

```
$(".topik").change(function() { 
     window.location.href = '/search/?q=' + this.value;
     });
```

---

When you click one input checkbox it takes its value and goes to the location with label name.
My code after selection appends all values to the string and on button click does the redirection.

```
 <ul>
        <li> <input class="topik" type="checkbox" value="label:topik1"></li>
        <li> <input class="topik" type="checkbox" value="label:topik2"></li>
        <li> <input class="topik" type="checkbox" value="label:topik3"></li>
        <li> <input class="topik" type="checkbox" value="label:topik4"></li>
        <li> <input class="topik" type="checkbox" value="label:topik5"></li>
        </ul>
        <button id="a">click</button>


    var t='/search/?q=';
var k;
var count=0;
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $(".topik").change(function() { 
     count++;
     if(count==1)
     t = t + this.value;
     else
     t = t +"|"+ this.value;

     alert(t);
     });
     $("#a").click(()=>{
     window.location.href=t;
     })
     });
```

Comment: What about this separator "|"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve that, you don't have to set window.location.href in your event function.

You could store the status of your checkboxes in an array, and use [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for generating the string

`label:Topic1|label:Topic2|label:Topic3` ,

and then you can determine in which event to set the value of window.location.href (could be when clicking a button).

Comment: I need to learn more to use an array, can you help me by setting an example with my code above, thank you